# How to change the underline color of md-input-container in angular4?

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I have been reading the docs for this (https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview) There is a section that says how to change the color of the line at the bottom of the md-input-container. But it is not clear to me what an attribute is nor is there a code example to refer to. It says the underline color can be changed using the color attribute of the md-input-container. In addition what I mean by underline is the animated underline that expands out as visible in the provided link. Could somebody explain more clearly what the attribute of md-input-container is, or provide some code. I have tried adding a directive called color, changing the color of md-input-container in css, amongst other things and I am not succeeding at this. If somebody could explain/show some code that demonstrates this, that would be very helpful. Thanks!

Here is some code, which I feel should work, based on the wording of that text. But it does not.

```
  <md-input-container
    color="yellow"
    class="input-half-width">
    <input
      [(ngModel)]="driftInfo.title"
      name="title"
      mdInput
      placeholder="Ange rubrik"
    >
  </md-input-container>
```

[image]

Comment: Also tried using a hex color, but that did not work either.

Comment: adding css did it not work ?

Answer (score 14):

## Change Colour Of Md-Input and Label When MAT-FOCUSED :

### label on focus colour change:

```
.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
    color: #027D7C !important;
}
```

### Input on focus colour change:

```
.mat-form-field-ripple {
    background-color: #027D7C !important;
}
```

Comment: still works in 2022 with Angular 12, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Add this in yout component `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`
it works in angular 6

example :

```
import {Component, Injectable, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

and in CSS file add the code

example :

```
.mat-form-field-label {
    color: white !important;
}
.mat-form-field-underline {
    background-color: white !important;;
}
.mat-form-field-ripple {
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Do you know the property to override the cursor color? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the only method I could find that's currently working in Angular 6+. Does removing view encapsulation have any negative effects?

Comment: Using ViewEncapsulation.None can leak these styles to other components. Overall, it's not a good practice.

Comment: @JoãoIgnacio you are correct, this would be better to add a second custom class so avoid mis-assigning them elsewhere

Answer (score 6):

Using angular material 7.3 this is working for me - to change the underline when textbox has the focus:

(in global styles.scss)

```
.mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-ripple {
    background-color: #69f0ae !important;
  }
```

Comment: propa solution is this

Answer (score 3):

This is how I removed mine in Angular 6.0.1

I know its for removing the underline, but you can follow the same procedure to change color e.t.c. Thanks

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: This method doesn't work on the latest Angular version.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it like this

```
::ng-deep .mat-input-underline{
    border-bottom: 1px solid red!important;
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't work on the latest Angular version.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is Due to `View Encapsulation` [git issues](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2745)

Make changes in your css

```
@Component({
  selector: 'input-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'input-overview-example.html',
   styles: [':host ::ng-deep .mat-input-underline {background-color: red}']
})
```

Check this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/baVmXVktIg3b43lvESpG?p=preview) for working example.

Answer (score 1):

****for Angular 10****

component.sccs

```
    :host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline {
        background-color: white !important; 
     }
     :host ::ng-deep .mat-focused .mat-form-field-underline .mat-form-field-ripple {
     background-color: white !important;
}
:host ::ng-deep input {
    color: white !important;
}
:host ::ng-deep input {
    color: white !important;
}
```

component.html

```
 <form>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label id="placeholder" class="buscador">Buscar...</mat-label>
        <input type="text" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" type="text" name="option" required minlength="3">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" name="option">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options | async" [value]="option">
                {{option}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
::ng-deep .mat-input-underline{
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

or what I do is give the angular material element a class and add it to styles.css or scss whichever extension you're using.  So it would look like this in styles (which is a global style sheet)

```
.mat-input-underline .<custom class name> {
    put your info you want to change here.
}
```

Comment: The `::ng-deep` method doesn't work on the latest Angular version.

Answer (score 0):

For angular 6+, We can just add styles line in the typescript (.ts) file of your project in the @Component section.

```
styles: [':host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline {height: 0px!important}']
```

The overall code design should be like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: '',
  templateUrl: '',
  styleUrls: [''],
  styles: [':host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline {height: 0px!important}']
})
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Colors are defined in material themes. You could custom your own theme, choosing yours colors: (https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-custom-theme).

Answer (score -2):

In your CSS file add

```
.mat-form-field-underline {
    background-color: black !important; // change black with your color
}
```